# Mechanize to follow meta refresh link

Tags: perl, refresh, mechanize

How can I get `Mechanize get()` to follow a meta refresh link?

My `get()` call is returning:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body text="#000000">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/TMP/4254358.41083527.html">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I cause the link to be followed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin module [`WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::FollowMetaRedirect`](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::FollowMetaRedirect)

Since you say that's not working for you, I suggest you use

```
$mech->follow_link(tag => 'meta');
```

Comment: I have to say that it doesn't work.  I tried `$mech->follow_meta_redirect;
` and the response content was what was there before.  I extracted the refresh link myself and did a `get` and I was able to get it.  I think that Plugin must be faulty.

Comment: @CJ7: See my update. But if the HTML is exactly as you show, then note that it is invalid because `<meta>` tags must appear within the `<head>` element. `WWW::Mechanize` may well be ignoring ones that appear in the `<body>`. Does the URL appear in the list given by `print $_->url for $mech->links`?

Comment: `$mech->follow_link(tag => 'meta');` is a nice solution.